# what is the purpose of this tmp variable in android sample bluetooth chat application

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I'm just analyzing one of android sample applications - the bluetooth chat: https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/project.html . I'm looking at the BluetoothChatService class ( https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com.example.android.bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatService.html ), at the constructor of its inner class called ConnectThread. There is such piece of code there:

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    (...)
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        (...)
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        (...)
        try {
            if (secure) {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_SECURE);
            } else {
                tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }
    (...)
```

I don't understand - why they first assign the object to the tmp value and then copy it to mmSocket attribute? They could do it a bit simpler, this way:

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    (...)
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        (...)
        try {
            if (secure) {
                mmSocket =  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_SECURE);
            } else {
                mmSocket =  device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly, because `mmSocket` is marked as final variable.

Let's see that your version of code. If method `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` or method `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` throws exception, the variable is not initialized. So the temporary variable makes sure that there is atleast `null` to be assigned to `mmSocket`.

That's the reason.

Comment: doesn't compiler detects if-else construction?

Comment: because if-else is in try-catch block the variable might not get initialized at all.